I want to display the coordinates of a point using tikz or tkz-euclide
Sometimes I need the coordinates of a point that I defined through intersections or by a transformation.
Is there any way to find those coordinates and display them easily using tikz or tkz-euclide ?
I found this post but I don't understand it : How to obtain the coordinates of a given point?
Thanks in advance !

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

I agree with samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, it's much easier to answer a question by giving code you can use. \tkzGetPointCoord is in the documentation for tkz-euclide. With TikZ you have \pgfextractx and \pgfextracty.

It's possible with tkz-euclide: (but I agree with pascal974, tkz-elements if you need calculations with your geometric figures is more efficient. It is possible to use only TikZ for your drawings. With TikZ you have \pgfextractx and \pgfextracty.
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(2,1){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(6,5){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(3,6){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,2){D}
  \tkzDrawLines(A,B C,D)
  \tkzInterLL(A,B)(C,D)
  \tkzGetPoint{I}
  \tkzDrawPoints[color=blue](A,B,C,D)
  \tkzDrawPoint[color=red](I)
  \tkzGetPointCoord(I){i}
  \tkzLabelPoint(I){$I : (\ix,\iy)$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I use very little calculations and most of it is very basic so I think "\tkzGetPointCoord(I){i}" will do very nicely. Thanks a lot !

Have a look at tkz-elements A simple example. Compilation in lualatex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\usepackage[mini]{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\tkzSetUpPoint[size=2,color=teal,fill=white]
\directlua{%
init_elements ()
z.A = point: new (1,1)
z.B = point: new (4,2)
z.C = point: new (2,4)
z.D = point: new (4,1)
L.AB = line : new ( z.A , z.B )
L.CD = line : new ( z.C , z.D )
z.I = intersection (L.AB,L.CD)
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines](0,0)grid(6,5);
    \tkzGetNodes
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,...,D,I)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,...,D,I)
    \tkzDrawLine(A,B)
    \tkzDrawLine(C,D)
    \tkzLabelPoint[below=40pt](I){\parbox{5cm}{$\mathrm{re}=\tkzUseLua{z.I.re}$\\$\mathrm{im}=\tkzUseLua{z.I.im}$}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


